# I want to interrupt the ddrescue and change the command and then resume it again.Is this possible?

Tags: hard-drive, lubuntu, data-recovery, resume, ddrescue

***I WANT TO SPEED UP THE DDRESCUE PROCESS AFTER RESUMING***

I am using `ddrescue` to recover video files from my external hard drive storage. The command I used:

```
sudo ddrescue -d -r 3 source destination logfile
```

Now Operation is running but is taking too much time. What can I do to speed up the process. The reason I am recovering is because I was having error while copying any data, error code was:

> Error splicing : input/output error

That is why I am using `ddrescue.`

I have 1TB of hard drive having 200GB of data like movies, mostly `.MP4`. I am using another hard drive of same company same size to store recovered file.

Can I change something in the previously mentioned command to speed up? Like adding `-n` option for no scrap, or adding bs value manually? I don't know what these things mean but I read somewhere it can speedup the process. Can I interrupt and change the command and resume?

If yes, what should be the suitable command for me? I am using Ubuntu installed in my pc (no live CD).

If it matters, I am using LOGFILE. Will changing bs affect logfile?

Comment: Please help me here.

Comment: Ses this: https://superuser.com/questions/431815/

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu, why did you tag Lubuntu? and why ask almost the same question multiple times?  To restore data quickly, just restore a backup,  What release of Lubuntu are you using? (the desktop & software stack varies on release details)

Comment: I was searching for ubuntu,couldn't find it so I added Lubntu,@guiverc,don't take it personally .I have already waited for two days straight but ddrescue speed is too slow. I just want my data back. I am still able to open few files from damaging drive.DDrescue has already recovered 41gb of data ,I want to speed up the process. Is tthere any other tool available to copy files faster with I/O errors, or should "bs" or "--skip-size"? I don't know,Please help. I have been using logfile from starting,I interupted the process of ddrescue ,resumed it in reverse order,but still speed is in B/s.